# Google app script to cut and paste a range from a google sheet to another google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put together a script that cuts a range from a google spreadsheet and pastes it to another spreadsheet. The script works fine as long as the source sheet is the first sheet in my document. How can I fix it so that the script grabs the right sheet no matter where it is in my document?

I'm very very new at this and mostly used code I found online. Probably made a very obvious mistake..

```
function CopyRangeTo_OtherSheet() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1O1gML-IeOkx6n6RhCavay6Zg9zflalcVs0qkB2yu7bE'); 
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
 var range = ss.getRange(2,4,sss.getLastRow()-1,9); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1WHoETM3QxV166ndnPW4Qv37Y6SBGPVw-CcEQxNpw0Co'); 
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet3'); 

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,50,9).setValues(data); 

  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1O1gML-IeOkx6n6RhCavay6Zg9zflalcVs0qkB2yu7bE');
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange("D2:H").clearContent();

}
```

Comment: see [mcve]  and [ask]. You need to provide error logs and mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of rows will be different in each sheet. `.getLastRow()` on a spreadsheet class only returns the last row in first sheet. getLastRow of sheet instead

```
ss.getLastRow()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your line `var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');` implies that you take the sheet with the name `Sheet1`.

This is the sheet you use to obtain your `values` from `range` and subsequently copy them.

If you want to copy / cut and paste values from a different sheet, simply paste the correct name of the sheet in `var ss = sss.getSheetByName('PASTE HERE THE NAME OF THE SHEET');`

> Small annotation:
>
> If the range you want to clear is the same from which you copied the
>   values, you do not need to define it again. You can simply replace the
>   lines
>
> ```
> var spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1O1gML-IeOkx6n6RhCavay6Zg9zflalcVs0qkB2yu7bE');
> var sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
> sheet.getRange("D2:H").clearContent();
> ```
>
> through
>
> ```
> range.clearContents();
> ```

### Also note:

`setValues()` only works if the range into which the values shall be set has the same dimension like the value range, i.e. the original range.

If your original range is `2,4,ss.getLastRow()-1,9`, then the number of rows is `ss.getLastRow()-1` and the number of columns `9`.

Thus, you need to define

```
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,ss.getLastRow()-1,9).setValues(data);
```

to adapt the row number dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! But changing the sheetname doesn't seem to fix the problem. The script only works if sheet1 is the first sheet in my document. If sheet1 is not the first sheet in my document the script doesn't work.

Comment: for the script to work, the dimension of the destination range needs to be the same like the one of the origin. I will update my answer to show how you can adapt the dimension dynamically.